# MySQL - INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... UNION 

Tags: mysql, insert, union

I'm having an issue with a fairly complex query where I need to store the ids from one table (based on heavy criteria) into a narrow, alternate table for future reference, but I keep running into a bad sql construct error.

If I run the following query by itself it works fine:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM accounts AS a
WHERE a.createdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND a.email NOT LIKE '%gmail.com')
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM accounts AS a
WHERE a.createdate < date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND a.email NOT LIKE '%yahoo.com') AND a.email NOT IN
(SELECT email FROM inactive_clients));
```

However, if I try to run same query with like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_backup_table (account_id) VALUES ($aboveQuery);
```

I get the following error:

```
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION DISTINCT (SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM accounts at line 1
```

I tried any number of parenthetical permutations and still received the same error.

Comment: You don't need the word DISTINCT anywhere in that query and it would be beneficial to turn your NOT IN (SELECT) into a proper LEFT JOIN/IS NOT NULL for performance reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the `INSERT INTO tblname (...) VALUES ...` syntax

You must use the `INSERT INTO tblname (...) SELECT ...` syntax

Try the Following:

```
INSERT INTO my_backup_table (account_id)
SELECT id FROM
(
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM accounts AS a
    WHERE a.createdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    AND a.email NOT LIKE '%gmail.com')
    UNION DISTINCT
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM accounts AS a
    WHERE a.createdate < date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    AND a.email NOT LIKE '%yahoo.com') AND a.email NOT IN
    (SELECT email FROM inactive_clients))
) A;
```

Comment: Lol, look familiar? It worked! Thanks again.

Comment: LOL !!! You asked about this similar UNION before ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19900/877 )

Comment: Ya, for a select into outfile. What keeps throwing me off is the 'derived' SELECT id.

Comment: You need neither the enclosing `SELECT id FROM (...) A`, nor the `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 2):

Rolando answered your question regarding the `INSERT` syntax, but I'd like to add some additional comments regarding the performance of this query.  First, you are DISTINCTing too many times.  You actually don't need `DISTINCT` anywhere in this query as `UNION` implies `DISTINCT`.  I'm not sure if the optimizer will optimize away the unnecessary `DISTINCT`s, but consider this:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
+---+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Additionally, `NOT IN (SELECT)` will execute the inner query for every row in the bounding query and is highly inefficient.  I come across this on a weekly basis with developers on my team and it causes problems every time.  Instead, rewrite the query as a `LEFT JOIN`.  You're also going to get a performance hit from the unindexable `LIKE %domain.com`.

Another consideration is, since this query will likely take a "while," in MySQL's default transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE READ, many of the rows in the tables in the `SELECT` statement will be locked due to gap locks, so will not be updatable.  For this reason, I suggest you run this query in READ-COMMITTED combined with MIXED or ROW based replication.

```
SET BINLOG_FORMAT=MIXED;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ-COMMITTED;

INSERT INTO my_backup_table (account_id)
  SELECT a.id
  FROM accounts AS a
  WHERE a.createdate >= date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  AND a.email NOT LIKE '%gmail.com')
  UNION 
  SELECT a.id 
  FROM accounts AS a
  LEFT JOIN inactive_clients ic USING(email)
  WHERE a.createdate < date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    AND a.email NOT LIKE '%yahoo.com'
    AND ic.email IS NULL;

 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (whatever it was before);
 SET BINLOG_FORMAT=(whatever it was before);
```

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the more indepth info, it's exactly why I keep telling people at work that we need a DBA on staff.